# Building a cooling system for a kneading machine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, manufacturing-engineering, cooling

I wanted to modify my kneading machine. In fact it can work for at maximum 5 minutes, and then I have to let it cool for 20 minutes (it is a very cheap model), and it is a problem for me.

So I was thinking of adding a sort of cooling system, for instance a fan (like that used in motherboards).

[image]

I was thinking of removing the red "hat" of the machine and replacing it with a bigger hat, so that there will be space for the cooling system.

But I have the following questons:

1) Do you agree with me with the position of "cooling ports" from with the air will enter and exit (IN, OUT)?

2) How can I realize the bigger hat? Which material?

3) How can I connect the bigger hat to the machine?

4) I was thinking of doing this modification because it is a cheap model and because I think that the only problem of using it for more than 5 minutes is the excessive heat. So if we solve it with a proper cooling system, I can use it for instance for 20 minutes. Do you agree with me about this last statement?

No problems about the electrical supply of the fan because I will build an external supply circuit for it.

Comment: to answer 1), we need to know the locaton of the motor in the casing, 2) and 3) dpend on what you can work with and how the red part is connected. For sizing the fan you need to provide motor power and the temp. range the motor operates in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hacking cheap appliances is off topic here.

Comment: disagree @PhilSweet if we didn't constantly ask "how can i improve this?" then there'd be no engineers at all

Comment: Do the more expensive kneading machines have cooling devices that allow them to be used for longer periods? If so, get one of them. The other thing to do is just remove the red cover when the machine is cooling - it's trapping the heat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motors used in inexpensive, occasional-use appliances often do not have cooling fans in them because they are not designed for continuous operation. This means that cutting holes in the top case of your mixer might not help get the heat out of the motor windings- unless you added a fan for this purpose. That would be a time-intensive proposition, requiring several hours. You then have to ask yourself the question of what is an hour of your time worth?

In general, if your appliance hits its thermal cutout after 5 minutes of operation, it is the wrong tool for the purpose and should be replaced by one of higher capacity.

An alternative solution is to buy a second mixer of the same type, and let the one cool down while using the other.

Comment: And what do you think about building one? I have seen that some middle-level kneading machines have inside a 24V, 250W electric DC engine, and it can be bought at about 30-40$ on the web. My doubt is always about its cooling system